# NameError: uninitialized constant GoalsController::Goal ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, nameerror

I'm making a website which will keep track of goals for the user. I'm currently getting a NameError when trying to create a model object to bind form fields to.

When I look up this error most of the time the situation is the same, but they have made the object plural (a.k.a. @goal = Goals.new), which is not the case here.
Another side query I have is in a form_for tag, one usually specifies a url. In my case I would normally make it the path for goals#create (the POST request), but my routes show no helper/path for this url. 
Thanks in advance.

Here is the controller goals_controller.rb:

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
  # GET request to /goals/new
  def new
    @goal = Goal.new
  end

  # GET request to /goals
  def index

  end
end
```

The full error:
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

```
NameError (uninitialized constant GoalsController::Goal):

app/controllers/goals_controller.rb:4:in `new'
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendering /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (14.8ms)
```

Comment: Please include the full text of the error, and specify which line it is pointing to

Comment: When you say, "they have made the object plural", do you mean that the model name is plural? If so, it should be singular. Can you post your `Goal` model class?

Comment: No I can't because I never made a model class smh thanks for helping me find the problem

Comment: ::Goal.new will solve the issue.